# Visual Studio 2015 moves undocked windows during debugging

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, remote-desktop

this has been bugging me for quite a while now.
I'm using two monitors and usually have the main window of Visual Studio open on the primary monitor and things like the solution explorer, call stack, error list, output etc. on the second monitor in two separate windows which I split vertically by using the `[Win] + [Left | Right]` shortcut.

In another environment, this works fine (VS 2013, different machine). Of course, the window positions etc. are different between debug and regular view, but that's not really an issue.

Whenever I start debugging, the solution explorer window moves towards the right on the second monitor. This might even affect the other window (which contains the Call Stack, Output etc.).
After a few debug sessions, the window will be barely visible any more because it has moved so far towards the right...

This is even worse when I have multiple solutions open because then the solution explorer window that I see is actually the one from the instance in the background...

Has anyone else experienced this? Any ideas how to fix this?

P.S.: I'm working on a windows server via a RDP session, maybe that contributes to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me.

1. Under the Windows menu, save the desired layout with "Save Window Layout". I named mine "Debug". This might have something to do with the old layout names.
2. Stop debug mode if your in it, and apply that layout with "Apply Window Layout".
3. Start debug mode.

My un-docked windows flash as if they are resizing, yet stay where I had them in the saved layout.

Comment: It seemed like it worked but the windows move even during debugging if I'm investigating an exception - suddenly the solution explorer window moves... if I reset the position then it might move as soon as I focus the main window.

Comment: Another possibility is video drivers on the machine require an update. I know its a generic answer, and most likely something you have done. Just covering all bases. I am currently using  GeForce 359.06.

Comment: It appears that hitting a breakpoint or exception is another mode. You will need to apply the layout you desire at that point as well.

Comment: I'm not sure about the graphics drivers. It's a virtual server I'm working on via rdp (which on itself could be part of the problem)... I'll try if I can save/restore the layout for breakpoints etc. - last time I tried it just always moved the window when I did that...

Comment: Sometimes the windows seem to forget all that again, but setting this separately for each "mode" seems to have helped a a lot. Thanks :)